# How to give file value in edit file input in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file, vuejs2

In a Vue regular setup, `/assets` is not served.

The images become `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...YII="` strings, instead.

To get the images from JS code, I use like this - `require('../assets/myImage.png')`.
But how to do it for file input?

Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<b-form-file
    id="fileinput"
    required
/>
```

**JS**

```
const photo = document.getElementById('fileinput').files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', photo);
fetch(`/assets/${image}`,{ method: 'POST', body: formData });
```

**File path** - `root/src/assets/a.png`

But I am getting `POST https://myurl.com/assets/a.png 404 (Not Found)`

I also tried `` fetch(`@/assets/${image}`,{ method: 'POST', body: formData }); ``.

But it didn't work.

Comment: Did you check weather new files are being created at `assets/` location?

Comment: No. There is no newly created file.

Comment: So your post and backend code that is supposed to save the file isn't working...

Comment: No. I am fetching file from local path in edit file input.

Comment: You can't read a while without user selecting or drag and dropping it due to security issues